# How to sum values for multiple table column based on class or id

Tags: php, html, html-table, calculated-columns

I have number of table in one page .
I want to calculate sum of all price column from all different tables & want to display that sum value as Grand total.

For example:- I have page like: Item you purchased

```html
<!-- table for fruit items -->
        <table>
               <tr>
                   <th>Item</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Apple</td>
                   <td>50</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Banana</td>
                   <td>40</td>
               </tr>
        </table>

     <!-- table for cloth items -->
        <table>
               <tr>
                   <th>Item</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Tshirt</td>
                   <td>500</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Jeans</td>
                   <td>600</td>
               </tr>
        </table>

     .
     .
     .
     <!--multiple tables for different categories -->
     .
     .
     .

     <!-- table for home items -->
        <table>
               <tr>
                   <th>Item</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>TV</td>
                   <td>5000</td>
               </tr>
        </table>

<!-- Grand total of all item price for all tables-->
<div>
     <label>Grand Total:</label>
     <div>6190</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you written any php code to try to attempt to get the sum?

Comment: @MrTechie no i hadn't

Answer (score 1):

declare the variable in above table.

```
<?php $grand_total = 0 ?>
    <!-- table for fruit items -->
            <table>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Item</th>
                       <th>Price</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Apple</td>
                       <td><?php $grand_total+= 50 ?> 50</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Banana</td>
                       <td><?php $grand_total+= 40 ?>40</td>
                   </tr>
            </table>
         <!-- table for cloth items -->
            <table>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Item</th>
                       <th>Price</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Tshirt</td>
                       <td><?php $grand_total+= 500 ?> 500</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Jeans</td>
                       <td><?php $grand_total+= 600 ?> 600</td>
                   </tr>
            </table>

         .

         <!--multiple tables for different categories -->

         <!-- table for home items -->
            <table>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Item</th>
                       <th>Price</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>TV</td>
                       <td><?php $grand_total+= 5000 ?> 5000</td>
                   </tr>
            </table>
    <div>
    <label>Grand Total:</label>
    <div><?php echo $grand_total ?></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your `<table>` tag, create a variable in PHP (initially set to 0) and increment it by each value in the Price column.

Your code would look like this:

`<?php $total = 0; ?>`

```html
<!-- table for fruit items -->
        <table>
               <tr>
                   <th>Item</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Apple</td>
                   <td>50</td>
                   <?php $total += 50; ?>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Banana</td>
                   <td>40</td>
                   <?php $total += 40; ?>
               </tr>
        </table>

     <!-- table for cloth items -->
        <table>
               <tr>
                   <th>Item</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Tshirt</td>
                   <td>500</td>
                   <?php $total += 500;?>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>Jeans</td>
                   <td>600</td>
                   <?php $total += 600; ?>
               </tr>
        </table>

     .
     .
     .
     <!--multiple tables for different categories -->
     .
     .
     .

     <!-- table for home items -->
        <table>
               <tr>
                   <th>Item</th>
                   <th>Price</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>TV</td>
                   <td>5000</td>
                   <?php $total += 5000; ?>
               </tr>
        </table>

<!-- Grand total of all item price for all tables-->
<div>
     <label>Grand Total:</label>
     <div>$<?php echo $total;?></div>
</div>
```

You can also look into PHP functions such as `number_format` to better format the total value.

Comment: this code not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Give individual classNames to field names. 
For example:

```
<td class="banana">50</td>
```

Then you have to write something like this in JavaScript.

```
var bananaArray = document.getElementsByClassName("banana");
var bananaSum = 0;
for(var i=0; i<bananaArray.length; i++)
{
    $bananaSum +=bananaArray[i].innerHtml or bananaArray[i].value;
}
```

Then create additional row for sum and append it to table.

```
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.innerHTML = "Sum";
    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
        td2.innerHTML = bananaSum; //this is bananaSum variable from for loop
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
```

Then get your table id and append this row to it:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId)";
    table.appendChild(tr);
```

That's all :)